# How to fetch resource in android from string

Tags: java, android, json

I have a json file  which contains name of resource that I want to use in my code, but i do not know how?
Json file

```
{
file1: "file1.xml",
file2: "file2.xml"
...
}
```

I need to do somethin like this

```
InputStream f1 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file1);
InputStream f2 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file2);
InputStream f3 = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file3);
```

Than use this in my code further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String rawFileName = "file1.xml"
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(rawFileName, "raw", context.getPackageName());
InputStream f1 = this.getResources().openRawResource(resId);`
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the `Resources#getIndentifier()` method a try, though you'll probably need to strip out the file extension:

```
public static int getIdentifierForRawXmlFileName(Context context, String fileName) {
    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    if (fileName.endsWith(".xml") {
        fileName = fileName.subString(0, fileName.lastIndexOf(".xml"));
    }
    return res.getIdentifier(fileName, "raw", packageName);
 }
```

Which you could use as:

```
final int rawId = getIndetifierForRawXmlFileName(this, "file1.xml");
final InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(rawId);
```